# How do I interpret 理不尽 in this situation?

Tags: translation, meaning

I was talking with my colleagues about work and my friend described the following situation:

The boss asked my friend to make a report for a meeting that they had at the end of the day. He worked really hard on it but then our boss never used it.

Drinking with them later that night, they described the boss/situation/work as 理不尽. I know the dictionary definition is *unreasonable* or *irrational* but it doesn't seem to fit this situation very well. It seemed to be used in the sense that it was troublesome or bothersome.

Is there a better way to express this feeling in English? I'm struggling to think of it.

Comment: over the top. outrageous

Answer (score 2):

'Unreasonable' is the right translation, and I don't understand why you think it does not fit, but if you are not satisfied with it, you may want to consider it as 'being forced into an unreasonable situation' or 'negatively affected (=being forced to work) unreasonably (= all the efforts were treated in a way to make them worthless)', etc.